# Rich Text Area field not saving if it contains multiple images

Tags: images, richtextarea

I am copy/pasting content into a rich text area field. Most of the time it saves properly, but if the value of that field contains more than 2 or 3 images, the record will not save properly. I do not see any errors, but when I look at the value after saving, it is missing all content after the 2nd or 3rd image.

I looked at the html source of the rich text area value, and it is only 1,000 characters or so. The value i am saving has about 5 images and each is only around 50kb. I looked at the storage limits for our org and we still have plenty of 'Data Storage' available.

Does anyone know what might be causing this, and what a solution could be? I am in lightning experience.

Comment: RTF fields are limited to 131072 characters

Comment: @cropredy I looked at the source html for the field value, and it's only about 1,000 characters

Comment: ah, my mistake, images are saved as links to `ContentReference`, an unqueryable SObject. I saved 5 images ea of 59K to a 32K RTF field and it worked fine. That said, ContentReference counts against your org's `FileStorage` limit - see `Setup | Company Info`

Comment: @cropredy thanks for the input. I found the problem. I right clicked and did 'inspect' in the image where I copied the content field from. It referenced a relative link which did not exist in my other org

Comment: sometimes the simplest answers elude us.  Write this up as an answer